# Como verificar os elementos próximos de um elemento específico numa matriz?

Tags: c, matriz

O objetivo é tentar encontrar no campus da faculdade possíveis locais para construção de um novo prédio. O usuário digitará a matriz que representa a planta da faculdade.

```
R = Ruas
P = Prédios
V = Área Verde
E = Estacionamento

R R R R R R R R R R R R       
R V V V V V V V V E E E   
R V P V V V P V V E E E   
R V V V V V V V V E E E   
R V V V V V V V V V V V   
R V V V V V P V V V P V   
R V P V V V V V V V V V   
R V V V V V V V V V V V   
R E E E E E E E E E E V  
R E E E E E E E E E E V   
R E E E E E E E E E E V  
R R R R R R R R R R R R
```

Após receber esta matriz do usuário, o programa irá marcar com a letra N (Novo) todas as possíveis posições para o novo prédio. As regras para o posicionamento do novo prédio são: ele não pode estar ao lado de ruas, estacionamentos ou outros prédios, ou seja, somente em posições rodeadas por áreas verdes como no exemplo abaixo:

```
V V V   
V N V  
V V V
```

Ao final do processo apresente para o usuário a matriz com a letra N em todas as possíveis

**Sou iniciante em programação em geral, e gostaria de dicas de como fazer esse algoritmo(Principalmente em como verificar quais elementos tem área verde em volta).

Answer (score 1):

Se meteres o campus numa matriz, o metodo mais directo (forca bruta) funciona bem

```
char campus[MAXROWS][MAXCOLS];

// input, preenche campus, obtem nrows e ncols

// para todos os elementos que nao estao na borda do campus
for (row = 1; row < nrows - 1; row++) {
    for (col = 1; col < ncols - 1; col++) {
        totalNV = 0;
        // conta N e V para todos os elementos da area 3x3 centrada em (row, col)
        for (i = -1; i < 2; i++) {
            for (j = -1; j < 2; j++) {
                if (campus[row + i][col + j] == 'N') totalNV++;
                if (campus[row + i][col + j] == 'V') totalNV++;
            }
        }
        if (totalNV == 9) campus[row][col] = 'N';
    }
}
```